# Correct braking technique on a manual transmission

Tags: manual-transmission, driving

I drive an old mechanical (non fluel injection) gasoline manual transmission car, and my approach to braking is pretty much as follows:

1. Cruising
2. Dissengage acceleratior, press clutch 100% in
3. Press break pedal accordingly

And now things change depending on if the reason I was breaking still exists (for example, the light change or the car in front accelerates)

*In case I need to fully stop I:*

4. Continue tu break till I come to a stop
5. Shift to neutral, disengage clutch

*If I need to resume:*

4. Down-Shift in to gear according to my speed
5. Rev-match and accelerate, carry on

I've been told many times this is not the correct way to do things because a car coasting in neutral or breaking in neutral isn't a car 100% under control.

Can anybody please elaborate and state the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I believe the "safe" way is minimizing the time coasting in neutral, as in an emergency situation you would have no way to accelerate until you get in gear. There is no real reason to press in the clutch while braking, you can brake with the clutch engaged, the engine will help you with the braking as well. Eventually you'll have to disengage the clutch anyways, but in this case - later.

Comment: Here's a good link to what is described above, it's called 'engine braking'.   http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/does-downshifting-engine-braking-cause-extra-wear-and-tear

Answer (score 1):

The correct procedure for braking in a manual transmission car is as follows

1. Driving as normal
2. Apply brakes with a gradual increase in pressure
3. Before the car stalls depress the clutch pedal
4. Slightly release pressure before a complete stop to ensure a smooth stop

When stationary for longer periods shift to neutral and release the clutch.

Each car is slightly different so you will need to learn with your own car what point to press the clutch in for step 3.