# Using first gear to decend a hill at a slow speed?

Tags: f-250

Recently I took my 1984 F-250 up a steep hill near where I live. On the way down I had it in 4-low (I had it in 4 on the way up too, it was a little rough) and first gear, and there was hardly any need to use the brakes, but I did anyway because I was afraid of over-revving. Was I right in doing so, or are were my fears unfounded?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This question is really a driving technique question. You're not asking for anything other than "How should I be driving my truck?"

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I thought it would fall under the "maintenance" category, but I see your point. I'll bear it in mind :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called engine braking. It's a good idea to engine brake during long downhills because riding your brakes causes them to "fade" - become less effective over time. That can cause you to lose stopping power and pick up speed you don't want. Engine braking doesn't "fade" so you can ride downhill indefinitely. Also your brakes last longer if you don't use them excessively.

There's some controversy on the wear and tear that engine braking causes if used regularly (say, every time you stop). But using it once in awhile to go down long hills is certainly safe for your engine. If you have fuel injection, engine braking also saves a bit of fuel because your engine is smart enough to cut the gas when the car's momentum is enough to keep it turning, whereas otherwise it would use a small amount of fuel to prevent it from stalling out.

In other words, you did the right thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "every time you stop"?

Comment: Like, every time you ever come to a stop sign, red light, etc. If you engine brake many times every day, some people think it could wear out your engine. Others disagree. See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/does-downshifting-engine-braking-cause-extra-wear-and-tear

Comment: Gotcha. Ty for the answer!

Comment: @Haveaniceday Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

A classic method of driving and it avoids "riding" the brakes - which may not be even side to side.

Comment: So no harm done?